# Start a terminal on login and show a message

Tags: 14.04, bash

How can I write a bash that will execute at login and starts a terminal with message.

*pseado code: .bash_login*

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal
echo "hello user $username";
```

Just trying to learn some bash skills. Can someone please point me to a good tutorial about this or show me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The [gnome-terminal manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) shows an option to execute a command in the terminal it opens.

```
   -x, --execute
             Execute  the  remainder  of  the  command  line  inside   the
             terminal.
```

But the catch is that once the command finishes, the terminal will close. [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1337622&page=2) has a solution for that:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "echo 'hello world' ; bash"
```

This will open the terminal and run the bash shell, which then runs the `echo` and then bash. This is essentially the same thing as a script like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo 'hello world'
bash
```

So `gnome-terminal -x script.sh` should run the `echo` and leave you with a bash shell. Once you exit that shell, the original (`bash -c`, or `#!/bin/bash`) shell will exit, and finally the gnome-terminal will exit.

You can also use the [Message of the Day](http://www.howtogeek.com/104708/how-to-customize-ubuntus-message-of-the-day/) feature, which runs after login on every terminal.